# Not all results returned from nearbysearch despite including types that are in those results

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm encountering cases where certain locations are being returned inconsistently based on the types I specify in my nearbysearch request to the `Places API`.

In some cases I need to specify fewer types to get the place to show up in the search. Here is an example:

When I run the query below with types **health|establishment**, I get one result:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=47.655335%2C%20-122.32975499&key=[MyAPIKey]0&rankby=prominence&radius=100&types=health|establishment&lang=en&sensor=false\
```

result:

```
...
"name" : "Ten Directions Design, Architects",
"types" : [ "establishment" ]
...
```

When I run the same query but without the **establishment** type, I get a different one result:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=47.655335%2C%20-122.32975499&key=[MyAPIKey]&rankby=prominence&radius=100&types=health&lang=en&sensor=false
```

result:

```
...
"name" : "Dr. William B. Lober, MD",
"types" : [ "doctor", "health", "establishment" ]
...
```

I think I should have gotten both results in the first query. Can anyone help me figure out why I didn't?

Here is another search in which I use keyword **piano** rather than the types, with the rest of the parameters the same, and get another establishment that is not included in the searches above. I think this location should also be included in the search that includes **establishment**.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=47.655335%2C%20-122.32975499&key=[MyAPIKey]&rankby=prominence&radius=100&lang=en&sensor=false&keyword=piano
```

result:

```
...
"name" : "Aaron Malver Piano Studio",
"types" : [ "establishment" ]
...
```